# For each and alert if not find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an easy barcode system. What it does is to loop through a `json-string` to find a match of the EAN code. If it does it will add the product based on the `product`. However. How should the code be changed in order to find if the EAN is not valid/found in the JSON-string. I thought below would solve it. But it didn't. It work if the EAN is valid. But I need to do some other stuff if the EAN is not found.

EDIT (complete JS)

```
<script>
var barcode = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pressed = false; 
    var chars = []; 
    $(window).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
            chars.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        }
        console.log(e.which + ":" + chars.join("|"));
        if (pressed == false) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (chars.length >= 9) {
                    barcode = chars.join("");
                    console.log("Barcode Scanned: " + barcode);
                    $('#barcode').myfunction(barcode);
            }
            chars = [];
            pressed = false;
        },500);
        }
        pressed = true;
    });


});
var search_json = <?= $ean ?>;
(function( $ ){
var match = "NO";
$.fn.myfunction = function(barcode) {

$.each(search_json, function(i, v) {
    if (v.ean == barcode) {
        alert(v.qty + ’ of ' + v.product + ’ added');
        match = "YES";
        return;
    }
    });
    if(match == "NO"){
    alert("EAN not found");
    }
      return this;
    }; 
    })( jQuery );
    </script>
```

Comment: How are you using this? Doesn't make sense extending `$.fn` with a function that doesn't  appear to have anything to do with the dom

Comment: I have a second function that record the barcode/ean-code and then call this function, passing along the barcode value

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Probably better ways to write what you have but it should still work depending on how you call it ... and still not clear why it is extending `$.fn`

Comment: Added complete JS above.

Comment: So what are you wanting it to do differently? Note you need to reset `var match` each time and I think you have similar problem with `pressed`. Declare the locals inside the functions you use them in that get called repeatedly

Comment: Its the part `if(match == "NO"){
    alert("EAN not found");
    }`I want to work somehow.

Comment: A working demo would help

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a simple find. I'm assuming the search json is an array of objects like so.

```
var jsonList = [ { ean: 1 }, { ean: 2 } ];
var barcode = 1;
var match = jsonList.find(obj => obj.ean === barcode);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: note that `Array.prototype.find()` doesn't have full browser support